# How to create an automated html input text field that will display values being fetched from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, contentful

I want to build an input text field which when clicked will show a list of values being fetched via the contentful API. The code doesnt seem to work when it reached the forEach loop. It works fine till the initArray. The forEach loop doesnt seem to work. I see all my data in the console.log of the initArray.

Am I missing something?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title> URL Builder </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://contentful.github.io/ui-extensions-sdk/cf-extension.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/contentful-ui-extensions-sdk@3"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="urlSearchContainer">
      <div class="cf-form-field">
        <input list="urlDataList" type="search" placeholder="Type your url here..." id="urlBuilder" class="cf-form-input">
        <datalist id="urlDataList">
        </datalist>
      </div>     
    </form>
    
    <script>
      "use strict"
      
      window.contentfulExtension.init(function(api) {
        api.window.startAutoResizer();
        
        // Set variables
        var urlDataList = document.getElementById("urlDataList");
        var urlInput = document.getElementById("urlBuilder");
                     
        function getUrlData(){
        //api.space.getEntries({'content_type[ne]': 'page-MBH'})
          var urlDataArray = [];
          api.space.getEntries()
          .then(function (entries) {
           entries.items.forEach(function (entry) {
              if(entry.fields.url){
                var urlData = entry.fields.url.en
                urlDataArray.push(urlData);
                //console.log('urldata', urlDataArray);
              }
         })
        })
          return urlDataArray;
        };
                
        function createUrlDropdown(){
          
          // Init data obj
          var data = getUrlData();
          var initArray = typeof data === 'object' && data instanceof Array && data.length > -1 ? data : [];
          
          console.log('ARRAY:: ', initArray);
          
          //Create and append url data list
          initArray.forEach(function(item) {
             console.log('item:: ', item);

            //Create a new <option> element.
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            console.log('option', option);
            
          option.value = item;
            console.log('value', option);
            
          // Add the <option> element to the <datalist>.
          urlDataList.appendChild(option);
          });
          
          for(i = 0; i < initArray.length; i++) {
            console.log('obj');
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = initArray[i];
            
            urlDataList.appendChild(option);
      }
    }          
        document.getElementById("urlBuilder").addEventListener("click", function(){
      createUrlDropdown();
    });
      });
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `getUrlData` function. `api.space.getEntries` returns a promise which you correctly use with `then`. The thing with promises is though that they're asynchronous (like so many things in javascript).

Meaning you initialize `urlDataArray` and make the call to contentful. And you fill this array when the call comes back. The thing is though `getUrlData` already returned an empty array.

```
    function getUrlData(){
      var urlDataArray = [];
      api.space.getEntries()
      .then(function (entries) {
        // this part is executed async
        entries.items.forEach(function (entry) {
          if(entry.fields.url){
            var urlData = entry.fields.url.en
            urlDataArray.push(urlData);
          }
        })
    })
      return urlDataArray;
    };
```

The best way to approach this IMO to change `getUrlData` to also return a promise.

```
function getUrlData() {
  // return this promise
  return api.space.getEntries()
    .then(function(entries) {
      // there is no need for another array
      // you can use map to grab the data you need
      return entries.items.map(function(item) {
        // map all the entries to the url strings
        return item.fields.url.en;
      })
    })
}

getUrlData()
  // only execute this when the data is there
  .then(function(urls) { console.log(urls); })
```

You code runs in a UI-extension but I also quickly changed your code in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/VGrwyB?editors=1111). It uses the Contentful CDA but the principles stays the same.

Hope that helps. :)